# Reload linux services in c

Tags: c, linux, service

I want to restart linux services such as apache, bind, proftpd and other in c and cgi code.

i use system() to do this, for example :

```
system ("service httpd reload");
```

also i set suid on compiled program and run it. but don't work and return error on permissions.

what should i do ?

edit:
my apache logs error :

```
[Wed Dec 21 21:07:13 2011] [error] [client *] cannot remove `/var/run/httpd.pid'
[Wed Dec 21 21:07:13 2011] [error] [client *] : Permission denied
[Wed Dec 21 21:07:13 2011] [error] [client *]
[Wed Dec 21 21:07:13 2011] [error] [client *] touch:
[Wed Dec 21 21:07:13 2011] [error] [client *] cannot touch `/var/lock/subsys/httpd'
[Wed Dec 21 21:07:13 2011] [error] [client *] : Permission denied
```

and same logs for named, proftpd, etc.

Comment: Is `service` in the path of whatever shell the system call is invoking? If not, it'll just spit out "service: command not found". Try an absolute path, e.g. `/usr/sbin/service http reload` instead.

Comment: no this is not my problem. i give permission error on some pid file that this services will remove or redefine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of things to check:

1. Make sure the compiled program has suid root (that is, the owner of the program is root).
2. Make sure the partition you are executing the program from is mounted without "noexec" option.

Comment: 3. Also make sure that the compiled program has no bugs and requires authentication to run; a bugged root SUID application running through CGI is quite a bit of a security hole.

Comment: You should also make sure that the mounted filesytem doesn't have the `nosuid` option set

Comment: 1. checked, no problem.
2. how should i check it?
3. all snippet of code run successfully, and i am aware of CGI security.

Comment: On GNU/Linux it's: 

  grep <partition> /proc/mounts | awk '{print $4}'

E. g.: 

  grep /home /proc/mounts | awk '{print $4}' 

You will get the list of options, make sure there is no "noexec" and "nosuid".

Comment: i think i have not problem on SUID because, in this snippet code i read and write from some files that has root permission without problem. is it true? also i use popen() to call systems programs in cgi.

Comment: Is there SELinux running on your system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root to run successfully the `/usr/sbin/service` command.

So your question is how can your application gain root privileges.

If your application is a CGI to which you (legitimately) don't want to give root access, you could code a wrapper program which is setuid root and which can only be run from you CGI (or at least, from the uid under which it is running).

But are you sure that you really want to run such things from CGI? (You could study how webmin works).

Comment: yes,absolutely!
when i run the CGI it give my real uid to 0. can you explain more about the wrapper i need?-
also about last question,i spend some time on kloxo that run a lighttpd with root user for administration and listen on 7778 port and separate it from apache web server that use for users.but directadmin use only one web server and do the same as mine.
-
generally i have some api in c, and request them from a web server that are not on the same server. i want specific a port,e.x. 7777, and restrict all request from unknown location with iptables.-but i would check webmin too.

Comment: Read a good book on Unix programming, since *setuid* is tricky to explain and to grasp. Eg http://basepath.com/aup/